# Debug Tomcat server taking long to start on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I created a debug configuration for my tomcat 8.5 server, but when I start it, it takes long and does not start.

I supplied -Xmx2048m and -Xms2048m and the arguments, and I added the webapps and directory of my workspace. The server works fine when it is not in debug mode.

Any help is appreciated greatly. I have tried importing the workspace again, refreshing, and cleaning but to no avail.

It is hung up on this line `2021-03-22 16:05:44.826 INFO 280658 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/demoau] : Initializing Spring root WebApplicatioNContext`

Comment: You might have some breakpoints on the startup code.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz i selected 'skip all breakpoints' but still facing the issue. Does the debugger use the default 8000 jdpa port